# Why copy doesn't work with dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

```
copy.copy(tracker.items())
```

In this code, tracker.items() is a dictionary, and the code in this line reports this error message:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 96, in copy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: can't pickle dict_items objects
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide a [reprex]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tracker.items()` is not a dictionary, it's a dict view of the key/value pairs in `tracker`. `tracker` is a dictionary. `copy.copy(tracker)` will work just fine, and you can always call `.items()` on the result if you only want to store the view of the key/value pairs.

The error seen is because `copy.copy` falls back to pickling and unpickling when the type doesn't define copy methods (which dict views do not), but copying the copy-able thing (the `dict`) is actually very efficient (no pickling needed at all), so you don't need to do try copying the view itself at all:

```
copy.copy(tracker).items()
```

or since `dict`s have a `.copy()` method, you can avoid the module import and just do:

```
tracker.copy().items()
```